# Is it ok to use same name for jquery event namespace and callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I was writing some jquery and I found myself inclined to use same name for event namespace and callback function as

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.fixTablescrollBug', fixTableScrollBug);
```

Although there hasn'e been any error or bug I noticed in my website, I am afraid this could be problametic like using same variable name and function name as:

```
var sameName = 1;
function sameName() {
  //code
}
// sameName variable is no longer exists
```

So is it fine to use same name for jquery event namespace and callback function?

Comment: read the article : http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: Yes, you can use same namespace as callback function name.

Comment: @HappyCoding I have read the whole article. That's about variable hoisting and scope. But they don't tell about jquery namespace and callback functions.